# What happens when my app no longer supports older iOS

Tags: ios, updates

If a user was using my app on iOS 8 and my latest release supports iOS 9 only. The user update OS to iOS9.

1. Does he get al alert to update app when he opens my app?
2. Can the user still use my app without updating it?
3. What happens for the deprecated code? Will the app crash while trying to access such APIs?

Comment: Mostly it will work with deprecated APIs taking no effect in execution.

Comment: @sweta.me That means iOS takes care of backward compatibility or at least that app does not crash. Also that I don't need to have backward compatible code?

Comment: For your latest codebase (depolyment target 9.0), if you don't want to support iOS 8.0 then you don't have to worry for backward compatibility, at all.

Comment: @sweta.me Yeah. That's not an issue. i want to know the behavior of app for someone using latest version on iOS but old version of app.

Comment: Refer my first comment :). It will work, with deprecated APIs having no effect. Rarely, it would crash. Rare. Why don't you try it out yourself?

Answer (score 1):

1. No alerts. If user will not update iOS your application will not be updated. Your project should be updated that now it requires iOS 9, see deployment target in your project settings. If you don't change this setting than it will get updated and you can have a crash if new API is used on old iOS.
2. If you didn't change server side in such way that it breaks compatibility than old version should still work.
3. This should be investigated by you. It depends on many factors. If you have setup project "deployment target" properly than update will not be performed on older iOS versions. This may be tricky if your application should support older versions of iOS. Not updated application will continue to work on new iOS even if deprecated API is used. Apple will simply reject updates witch are using deprecated API but still maintains that API. Once I had a problem since `UIAlertView` was deprecated and old application had new bug where `UIAlertView` was not respecting application orientation. I had to do a tricky code which detected if `UIAlertController` (I prefer this approach instead detecting iOS version) is available than use it and if not than fallback to `UIAlertView` was used.

During application update the biggest problem you can create is setting compatibility or database comp compatibility. So you should be careful with that.